# Is equicontinuity independent of the chosen metric of the state space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, equicontinuity

There already exist several posts on similar questions, but I could not find any, which really gives a precise answer to my problem.

Let $A \subseteq C([0,T],E)$, where $E$ is a topological space and C$([0,T],E)$ denotes the set of all continuous functions from $[0,T]$ to $E$. Assume I am given a metric on $E$, let me call it $d$, which induces the prescribed topology on $E$.

Then, equicontinuity of $A$ means $sup_{f \in A}d(f_{t_n},f_t) \to 0$ for each $t \in [0,T], (t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $t$. One usually does not find this as the definition of equicontinuity, but I think this is an equivalent way to express it, right?

Now, suppose someone considers a topologically (i.e. "weakly") equivalent metric, $\rho$, on $E$. Is equicontinuity of $A$ invariant under switching between such equivalent metrics? Intuitively, this should be the case, but I would very much like to have clarification for it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is negative. Here is a very simple example: For $a\in [0,\infty)$ consider $f_a:[0,1]\to \mathbb [0,\infty)$, $x\mapsto a+x$. Of course, the family $A=\{f_a: a\ge 0\}$ is equicontinuous with respect to the usual (translation-invariant) metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ on $[0,\infty)$. Now, consider the metric $\delta(x,y)=|x^2-y^2|$. It is easily seen that this is a metric which gives the same topology as $d$ (continuity of the square function and the square root).  But $A$ is not equicontinuous with respect to $\delta$: 
$$\sup\{\delta(f_a(x),f_a(0)):a\ge 0\} = \sup\{|2ax+x^2|:a\ge 0\}=\infty$$
for each $x\neq 0$.

Comment: I totally understand your example and still I am puzzled due to the following observation: I consider the space of continuous functions $C:=C([0,T],E)$ with the topology of uniform convergence, where $E$ is a metric space. Since $[0,T]$ is compact, this topology will not change when I replace the metric on $E$ by a topologically equivalent metric. Now assume I have a compact subset $A \subseteq C$. By Arzela-Ascoli, this set is equicontinuous. Now, compactness is a topological property, so $A$ remains compact when I change metrics on $E$.

Comment: But then, again bei A.-A.-theorem, also w.r.t. this new metric on $E$, the set $A$ is equicontinuous. Does this mean that equicontinuous is in fact invariant under a change of metric on the state space, if it is actually compact?

Comment: At least, this would fit together with your counterexample, because in your situation, the condition that $\{f(x)_a\}_a$ be precompact in $\mathbb{R}$ (which is necessary for compactness) is clearly fulfilled if and only if the set in which $a$ varies is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, but then your contradiction in the end does not occur.

Comment: The point is that the range $E$ should be a *uniform* space to define equicontinuity, there is no such thing if $E$ is just a topological space. The two metrics on $E=[0,\infty)$ in the example induce the same topology but different uniformities. If $E$ is a compact topological Hausdorff space then there is a *unique* uniformity inducing the topology.

Comment: I see. But I am still puzzled by what I posted above. It seems that, on the one hand, compactness is clearly a purely topological property, and the topology on $C$ does not depend on the actual metric used to metrize the prescribed topology on the state space (this is correct, isn't it?), but on the other hand, a necessary property for compactness, namely, equicontinuity, might hold or hold not, subject to such a change of metric. How should one understand this correctly?

Comment: I think that already the *topology of uniform convergence* depends on the uniformity on the range. $f$ close to $g$ means that $f(x)$ is uniformly close to $g(x)$ for $x\in [0,T]$.

Comment: So, essentially, you are saying that it is NOT true that the topology of uniform convergence in the above situation is independent of the chosen metric on the state space? I thought, this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3312318/360486 hat settled this in an affirmative way.

Comment: Okay, it seems that my previous comment is wrong because, as you said, the topology of uniform convergence is the compact open topology on $C(X,E)$ for $X$ compact. It thus follows indeed, that also Arzela-Ascoli ($F\subseteq C(X,E)$ is relatively compact in the compact open topology if and only if $F(x)=\{f(x):f\in F\}$ is relatively compact in $E$ and $F$ is equicontinuous) holds for every uniformity on $E$ which induces the topology of $E$. The example shows that this independence of the uniformity is lost for families which are not pointwise relatively compact.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I agree. However, if you (or anyone else) can provide a nicely written source for such general versions of Arzela-Ascoli, I would appreciate it. My only reference so far is General Topology from Kelley.

Comment: In Engelking's book *General Topology* there is a version of Arzela-Ascoli for general topological spaces: Under very mild conditions on $X$ and $E$ a subset $F$ of $C(X,E)$ is relatively compact if and only if it is pointwise relatively compact and *evenly continuous*, i.e., for all $x\in X$ and $y\in E$ and neighbourhoods $V$ of $y$  there are neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and $W$  of $y$ such that the conditions $f\in F$ and $f(x)\in W$ imply $f(U)\subseteq V$. I must confess that Engelking is great as a reference book but a nightmare if you want to learn topology.

Comment: Thank you. Also, this post and answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3175609/360486 might be valuable for some of you. I just discovered it.